# modify value of JSON obj with known location in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In a JSON file of unknown complexity I need to modify a specific value of which I have the location.

If this is my JSON:

```
{
    "first": {
        "beans": [{
            "joystick": {}
        }, {
            "adolf": {
                "dolphin": "this has to change"
            }
        }]
    },
    "second": {}
}
```

How do I change the value at this location of `str`:

```
var str = 'root["first"]["beans"][1]["adolf"]["dolphin"]'
```

Comment: convert it to string modify the string and again convert it to JSON

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I'd do that?

Comment: Is `eval()` an acceptable solution?

Comment: eval is acceptable, but I would prefer something more elegant than this: eval('json["first"]["beans"][1]["adolf"]["dolphin"] = "new value"');

Comment: It would be `eval(str + ' = "Some new value"');` - where does `str` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've parsed your JSON you can do something like this:

```
function changeProperty(obj, strProp, newValue) {
    var re = /\["?([^"\]]+)"?\]/g,
        m, 
        p,
        o = obj;
    while ((m = re.exec(strProp)) && typeof o[p = m[1]] === "object")
        o = o[p];

    if (p)
        o[p] = newValue;
}

changeProperty(root, str, "Some new value");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D6ECW/

Or if using `eval()` is acceptable you can do this:

```
eval(str + ' = "Some new value"');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D6ECW/1/

Note that both ways assume the chain specified in `str` actually exists.

Comment: The first method is what I'll use. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it

```
var variable = {
    "first": {
        "beans": [{
            "joystick": {}
        }, {
            "adolf": {
                "dolphin": "this has to change"
            }
        }]
    },
    "second": {}
}

alert("Before: " + variable.first.beans[1].adolf.dolphin);

variable.first.beans[1].adolf.dolphin = "my new string";

alert("After: " + variable.first.beans[1].adolf.dolphin);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gauravmuk/dE49m/)

Comment: The str is a variable so what i need is a process of getting to your JSON.bla.bla method

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

```
jQuery.parseJSON(str);
```